# Unknown (custom?) part

Tags: components, identification

The photo below shows a part  that I am trying to find a specification for. I suspect that it is a microcontroller, and is part of a larger device that is essentially a timer. It clearly bears the National Semiconductor logo.

[image]

However, I cannot find this device via searching, and it doesn't seem to fit into the National Semiconductor [device naming conventions](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa039c/snoa039c.pdf). Is it plausible that this might be a part custom-made by N.S. for the larger device manufacturer? Is this kind of thing done?

Comment: I think is a Freesacale MCU

Comment: What does the device that the part is in do?  Is it a power supply?  Thermostat?

Comment: Yes, this kind of thing is done! I don't have enough experience to speculate on the rest, but if you have enough money, you can get custom part numbers.

Comment: @CHendrix - a timer

Comment: @MarkoBuršič: NatSemi manufacturing Freescale parts?

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Is that a brand?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Yeah, Im wrong it's National Semiconductor logo, who knows could some analogue part. There is no description what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is... I wouldn't say "common" per se, but not unheard of for semiconductor manufacturers to create or manufacture custom (ASIC) or custom-screened (although standard under the hood) parts for very large customers with no publicly trackable part number. At a cost, of course.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect it's a 'house numbered' microcontroller, probably an OTP or mask-programmed [COP8](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cop8sac7.pdf) series.

See if this matches the use of the pins:

[image]

It's not unusual for such chips to be house numbered if they're supplied in relatively large quantity.

Answer (score 2):

Custom or semi-custom parts with the customer's "house number" are quite common. Especially with integrated circuits. It is not unusual to open a mass-produced item and find chips that have only OEM part numbers.

There have been a few cases where the community has "reverse-engineered" a mystery part in a particularly venerated product (legendary synthesizers, popular game consoles, etc.) but that is extraordinarily rare.